# Exceptions where the exception handler is in a separate module

Tags: python, exception, module

Consider the following two modules, prog.py and err.py.  both of which are examples of a much larger program that exhibits this problem.  I need to separate out the functionality into smaller source files, each  with a test bench.

Err.py includes a test bench.   When it creates a prog object, depending on how the exception is called, the exception is caught or not.

It seems that even though prog.py imports err objects in a "from err import *" statement, the module name is still inferred (wrongly?), but seems the err it refers to is not the same one as the module itself

Is this a bug in Python 2.7 or is it intended behaviour?

simply get both files and run err.py to see what I mean..

The first file:

```
#prog.py

from err import *



class prog(object):
    def func1(self):
        raise MySubError

    def func2(self):
        doError()
```

And the second file:

```
#err.py
import prog
import inspect
import sys

class myError(Exception):
    pass

class MySubError(myError):
    pass

def doError():
    raise MySubError

if __name__=="__main__":

    p=prog.prog()


    try:
        doError()
    except MySubError as er:
        print type(er)
        print "Captured 1"
    except Exception as er:
        print type(er)
        print "Not Captured 1"        

    try:
        p.func1()
    except MySubError as er:
        print type(er)
        print "Captured 2"
    except Exception as er:
        print type(er)
        print "Not captured 2"


    try:
        p.func2()
    except MySubError as er:
        print type(er)
        print "Captured 3"
    except Exception as er:
        print type(er)
        print "Not captured 3"
```

It seems to me as though somehow err should know what module it is and the exception should be err.MySubError, rather than just MySubError.  I can get the module, but not the instance.....

Output:

```
<class '__main__.MySubError'>
Captured 1
<class 'test.MySubError'>
Not captured 2
<class 'test.MySubError'>
Not captured 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that python doesn't know `err.py` is the same as your main script. Normally a module is only imported once, but when the main script imports itself as a module, python gets confused and you're actually loading `err.py` twice. (I'm not aware of any good reason for that; maybe @Latty can be more specific).

You can see the problem with this simple script:

```
# File: recur.py
import recur
print "This is the module"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "This is main"
```

If you run it you will *not* get infinite recursion, because modules are only imported once. But you'll see "This is the module" twice.

As long as your main script does not import itself (directly or indirectly), there's no problem with importing exceptions from one module to another. There's also no problem with having two interdependent modules A and B that each import the other: Try `import A` and you'll see that each of them is only loaded once.

**Edit:** Though I really think you should avoid importing your main script as a module, I just thought of a fix for your example:

```
# err.py
...
if __name__=="__main__":
    from prog.err import *     # add this line
```

This will replace all the duplicate script classes with their module versions, and everything will work as intended.

Comment: Yes I know of this and it makes sense.  What does not make sense is the class naming of the exception being changed.  I still can't see a reason for it. After all, ultimately it is the same class instance.  I've not used exec, I've just used a module function testerr.TestError() and called that from both the modules, that way they will both work with the global test module.

Comment: Jason: But it's not the same class instance, given the way you have structured the code. Perhaps Latty and alexis can correct me if I'm wrong but I believe: since you are doing `from err import *` inside `prog.py`, that makes new local copies of everything in `err.py` inside `prog.py`. That's why in prog.py the exception class is named `err.MySubError`, and inside err.py it is named `__main__.MySubError`. I believe you are actually raising two different exceptions, depending on where the `raise` is.

Comment: @alan, you are wrong. :-) Importing exceptions from one regular module to another works as expected, I've tried it in the past. The problem is that python does not recognize that the script is the same as the module. The only excuse I can imagine: Script names don't need to be valid module names, and they have no place in the module import path, so python has no good way to keep track of them.

Comment: @Jason, python does not recognize the module `err` and your main script as "the same class instance". That's the sole extent of the problem. If you define your errors in `prog.py` and import them into your main script (and do NOT import `err.py` anywhere), everything will work fine.

Comment: `@alan, you are wrong. :-)` Well, it won't be the last time :-)

Comment: Haha, well you asked us to tell you!

Comment: `from prog.err import *` Now that's what I call a true circular import! ;-)

Comment: And yet it fixes the aliasing problem instead of making it worse :-)

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that `err` actually acts as two different modules, essentially.

The main module that is run in Python is called `__main__`. Everything executed is put into it's namespace. What is happening here is you are then importing the module into your other script and it's called `err`, so they are not considered the same.

This is a little bit weird, but it's necessary to keep the way the Python import system works consistent. The best answer here is to move your exceptions outside of your script being called as `__main__`. This is good design anyway, as you are essentially creating a circular import here.

Comment: So instead of just err.py I have to have err.py and testerr.py?
The problem is that there is a rule that all modules have to have a test fixture within them. I guess I could use exec() to call err's test harness but that would be a bit hacky.

Comment: OK, I don't like it as it to me seems like an incolsistency.  The exception raised as MySubError should keep it's type and not be renamed just because of the way it is imported.  But to get me going again I'm happy to move the module test externally as I've found importing testerr in err and calling it's test function works in all synarios.

Comment: Definitely don't use `exec()`, that will make your aliasing problems worse. Just avoid importing your script into itself, and it will work as you expect. Python is really good at keeping track of namespaces across imports.